# Copying Excel Formulas In a Sequence Greater Than 1

Tags: excel

I am trying to input a formula in to a worksheet and drag it down so that the source cell increases by 43.

i.e. I have a cell formula: `=FAB!U1638` and I want the next formula to read `=FAB!U1681` and the next `=FAB!U1724` and so on. This is an increment of 43 each time.

However, when I drag the formula down it only increases by 1 cell at a time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula for the following:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("FAB!U",(1638+((ROW()-1)*43))))
```

You will need to play with this to get the outcome you desire. Imagine the above was put into cell A1, 1638 is the first row in your question, add on 43 times the row you are on minus one. So first row is 1, minus 1 is 0, 0*43 is 0, so you are still left with 1638.

Move to the second row and it is 1638, add your row 2, minus 1 gives you 1, 1 * 43 is 43, so you have 1638+43=1681.

Concatenate just joins `FAB!U` with the outcome of that formula.

Indirect makes it a cell reference.

Try to understand and have a play before just putting sticking it in.

Answer (score -1):

Try entering the first two formula, highlight them, and then drag down to fill.